# xpath preceding child issue

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Building a webscraper to scrape this page http://espn.go.com/nba/teams in order to fill a database with all the team names and their corresponding divisions using the scrapy python library. I am attempting to write my parse function however I still don't exactly understand how to extract the corresponding division name to match each team.

[1] https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv1n49rg4p6p2yh/2014-12-29%2014.08.07-2.jpg?dl=0

```
def parse(self,response):
    items = []
    mex = "//div[@class='span-6']/div[@class='span-4']/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li"
    i=0
    for sel in response.xpath(mex):
        item = TeamStats()
        item['team'] = sel.xpath(mex + "/div/h5/a/text()")[i]
        item['division'] = sel.xpath("//div[@class='span-6']/div[@class='span-4']/div/div/div/div[1]/h4")
        items.append(item)
        i=i+1
    return items
```

My parse function is able to return a list of teams and a corresponding divisions list which lists ALL divisions. Now I'm not really how to specify the exact division, as it seems to me that I must navigate from the team name selected (which is represented by item['team'] = sel.xpath(mex + "/div/h5/a/text()")[i] ) up the DOM by using the preceding child relation (was going to include a website that I've been following as a tutorial however I don't have 10 reputation points) to get the RIGHT division, but I'm not sure how to write that...

If I'm on the wrong track with this, let me know as I'm no expert with XPath. I'm actually not even sure if I need a counter as if I remove the [i] then I just get 30 lists with all 30 teams.

Comment: Please go through your past questions and *accept the answers* that helped to solve your issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make it simpler.

Each division is represented with `div` with a `mod-teams-list-medium` class. Each division div consist of 2 parts:

- div with class="mod-header" containing the division name
- div with class="mod-content" containing the list of teams

Inside your spider it would be reflected this way:

```
for division in response.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//div[contains(@class, "mod-teams-list-medium")]'):
    division_name = division.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "mod-header")]/h4/text()').extract()[0]
    print division_name
    print 

    for team in division.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "mod-content")]//li'):
        team_name = team.xpath('.//h5/a/text()').extract()[0]

        print team_name
    print "------"
```

And here is what I'm getting on the console:

```
Atlantic

Boston Celtics
Brooklyn Nets
New York Knicks
Philadelphia 76ers
Toronto Raptors
------
Pacific

Golden State Warriors
Los Angeles Clippers
Los Angeles Lakers
Phoenix Suns
Sacramento Kings
------
...
```

Comment: Awesome! I initially thought it was something as such because it seemed complicated to have to start at a child node then traverse backwards, this way I'm kind of starting higher in the DOM and picking the relevant child nodes that I'd want.